# How to get Eclipse CDT to parse .h.in files like .h files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, syntax-highlighting, file-association

I'm editing a `config.h.in` file for my project, and I want syntax highlighting like in `.h` files. I added `*.h.in` as a file type of C++ headers using Eclipse' preference dialog, closed the app and restarted it - but the file is still treated like plain text. Is this because of the double-extension? If not, can I do something about it (other than renaming the file of course)?

I'm using Oxygen.3 on GNU/Linux.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue: the patterns `*.h_in` and `config.h.in` work, but `*.h.in` does not. Please report it to Eclipse CDT: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: @howlger This sounds like [bug 422923](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422923).

Comment: @HighCommander4 Yes, good finding.That answers the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @HighCommander commented, this is indeed the known Eclipse bug [422923](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422923).